# Using the same EventArgs instance for multiple events, is this code smell?

Tags: c#

I have a custom EventArgs class that looks something like this:

```
public class PacketEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public byte[] Packet {get; protected set;}
    public PacketEventArgs(byte[] packet)
    {
        Packet = packet;
    }
}
```

And I have the following code that executes inside a tight loop:

```
PacketEventArgs e = new PacketEventArgs(packet);
OnPacketReceived(e); //raise PacketReceived event
//do something
OnBeforePacketConsumed(e); //raise BeforePacketConsumed event
//do something
OnAfterPacketConsumed(e); //raise AfterPacketConsumed event
```

Is it code smell to reuse the same PacketEventArgs instance for all 3 events? Are there any reasons why I should create a new PacketEventArgs instance for each event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that *generally* that pattern is not code smell. Since your PacktEventArgs class is essentially immutable (handlers of the event can't change its properties and there's no "answer" or "cancel" component of it), then no, its not code smell. No reason not to reuse it.

Your specific one does have an issue, as pointed out by Ksv3n - handlers of the event could change the individual bytes in the Packet property. That may not be your intention and so you may want to change how the PacketEventArgs is structured. But that doesn't change the fact that the pattern itself is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Tim and Ksv3n's answers, a compromise between performance and immutability could be:

```
public class PacketEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public byte[] GetPacket() { return packet.ToArray(); }

    private byte[] packet;

    public PacketEventArgs(byte[] packet)
    {
        this.packet = packet;
    }
}
```

The consumer can only ever get a copy of the data. Furthermore, using a method rather than a property might help convey the feeling that something is generated, rather than existing data returned. Therefore the same `PacketEventArgs` can be used.

If you do not expect many consumers on the events, this would be my preferred design.